# Search on multiple sheets and return first row/header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create inventory locator while searching through multiple sheets

```
'url01','sheet1'
Rack 1  | Rack 2  | Rack 3  | Rack 4  |
--------+---------+---------+---------+
item01  | item03  | item05  | item09  |
item02  | item06  | item04  | item07  |
item08  |         |         | item10  |

'url01','sheet2'
Rack 1  | Rack 2  | Rack 3  | Rack 4  |
--------+---------+---------+---------+
item11  | item13  | item15  | item19  |
item12  | item16  | item14  | item17  |
item18  |         |         | item20  |
```

searching for item and return the Rack number/header

```
'url02','sheet1'
Item    | Rack#  |
--------+--------+
item11  | Rack 1 |
item05  | Rack 3 |
item15  | Rack 3 | ... and so on
```

Using `=INDEX` `=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("url01","sheet1!1:1"),MAX(IF(IMPORTRANGE("url","sheet1!A$2:D$100")=A2,COLUMN(A2:D100),0)))`

I was able to get locations on single sheet, but I'm looking for a way to automatically search multiple sheets and return their location.

If this is possible

B'rgrds,

Comment: Share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet. In Column A of some new sheet within that spreadsheet copy (perhaps called "Import"), create an IMPORTRANGE formula that accesses *each* remote sheet in this way: `=IMPORTRANGE("url01","sheet1!A1")`. This retrieval of one cell is just to allow you to authorize the IMPORTRANGE to each sheet in an easy way. If you have five remote sheets to connect, you'll have five separate IMPORTRANGE formulas in this "Import" sheet. Once you've done that, share the link to this spreadsheet copy in your post. Then the volunteer contributors here can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This one is giving me a head scratch, the problem is you're using multiple sheets and tables. For whatever reason I cannot seem to join the tables together seamlessly. With the below formula it pulls the header of each column that has a matching item. However it will not pull any information after URL01. This formula also allows for multiple Racks in case an item exists in more than one, it will list each rack horizontally. Hopefully someone else here can assist to button this up.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE({IMPORTRANGE("URL01","SHEET1RANGE");IMPORTRANGE("URL01","SHEET2RANGE");IMPORTRANGE("URL02","SHEET1RANGE")})},"Select Col1 where "&JOIN(" or ", ARRAYFORMULA("Col"&COLUMN($A$1:$Z$100)&" = '"&A2&"'"))))
```

This is automating checking Col1, Col2, Col3, etc... until Col26 for the matching item. If you're going to have more items possible in a single Rack then expand the **$Z$1** to a larger Column such as **$AZ$1** would double it.

**EXAMPLE:**

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Sheet 3 with formula

[image]